# java regex detect \n

Tags: java, regex, latex, newline, replaceall

I am trying to delete LaTeX comments in a string:

input string:

> \begin{comment}inside \n comment 1  \end{comment}  something outside comments \begin{comment} inside comment 2 \end{comment} after comment 2

output:

> \begin{comment}inside comment 1  \end{comment}  something outside comments  after comment 2

Desirable output:

```
something outside comments after comment 2
```

Sample Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "\\begin{comment}inside \n comment 1  \\end{comment}  something outside comments \\begin{comment} inside comment 2\\end{comment} after comment 2";
    System.out.println(input.replaceAll("\\\\begin\\{comment\\}(.*|[\\s]*|\\n*)\\\\end\\{comment\\}", ""));
    }
```

So the problem is that this regex is not detecting `\n`.

I used the following link to form the regex :

http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either compile your `Pattern` with the [`Pattern.DOTALL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) option, or add the equivalent flag expression `(?s)` to your regex, so that `.` matches `\n`. Also, you regex doesn't seem to be working, try the following:

```
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("(?s)\\\\begin\\{comment\\}.*?\\\\end\\{comment\\}", ""));
```

Comment: System.out.println(input.replaceAll("(?m)\\\\begin\\{comment\\}(.*|[\\s]*|\\n*)\\\\end\\{comment\\}", "")); gives the same result...Also tried Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\\\begin\\{comment\\}(.*|[\\s]*|\\n*)\\\\end\\{comment\\}");

System.out.println(input.replaceAll(p.toString(), ""));